# iOS OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff

Tags: ios, xcode, onesignal, ios-app-extension

I am working on an iOS app which integrates push notifications using OneSignal. I've followed the iOS SDK setup guide and everything did work out fine but since I did the latest xcode update and macos updates I can't build the app for release or just on a physical device.

I get the following error about code signing the OneSignal extension:

FYI: The main target's bundle identifier is `com.example.ios.app`

```
CodeSign /Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-detsaukwwypeutcadzxgviircfje/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex
    cd /Users/pathToProject
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: Me (##########)"
Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.example.ios.app.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension"
                      (######-####-####-####-######)

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign E7160941E1D4E45D870F30CB31F3EC30BFB0ABBA --entitlements /Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-detsaukwwypeutcadzxgviircfje/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/myApp.build/Release-iphoneos/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.build/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-detsaukwwypeutcadzxgviircfje/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex

/Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-detsaukwwypeutcadzxgviircfje/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I've done some research but haven't found anything that was of any help.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension` Bundle Identifier to be {your app's bundle ID}.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.

Unless your actual app's Bundle ID is `com.example.ios.app`, the bundle ID `com.example.ios.app.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension` will not work.

Once you change the Bundle ID, you can enable Automatic provisioning and it should work.

Comment: I had the same issue, so I changed the bundle identifier of my extension to the same bundle id as my apps bundle id but it didn't help. What to do now?

Comment: I have changed my one signal bundle id with the app bundle id and it works. But when i create build for testing. The app is downloaded from diawi link but unable to test because the app icon is disable. Any help?

Comment: I switched from Cocoa Pods to SPM and the app was building and running fine, but failed App Store Connect verification for this issue.  Your solution worked for me too.  Thanks!